# proper way to right align buttons on a bootstrap based web form?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a web form that is using the Bootstrap framework.

I would like to right align the "Save" & "Cancel" buttons when the form is displayed on a full size screen.

What is the proper way to do this using Bootstrap 3 css?

```
 <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <input type="reset" value="Cancel" class="btn btn-default btn-danger" />
        </div><div class="col-md-3">
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default btn-success" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-9">
        <input type="reset" value="Cancel" class="btn btn-default btn-danger pull-right" />
    </div><div class="col-md-3">
        <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default btn-success pull-right" />
    </div>
</div>
```

You need to add the `pull-right` helper class.

Docs: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes-floats

Answer (score 2):

Let's try this:

```
 <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <input type="reset" value="Cancel" class="btn btn-default btn-danger pull-right" />
        </div><div class="col-md-3">
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default btn-success pull-right" />
        </div>
    </div>
```

Just put `pull-right` in the class to make it right align. Note that if you want to re-order the button just put the right-most on the upper line.

Answer (score 1):

Try using one of the helper classes of Bootstrap for floating of objects. 
You can use **.pull-left** for *float:left;* or **.pull-right** for *float:right;*

This should align the buttons correctly on the right side and with the right paddings.

Source: [Bootstrap Documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#helper-classes)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger">Cancel</button>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Save</button>
</div>
```